# wget and PDFFileReader - Could not read malformed PDF file

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, wget, pypdf

I'm trying to scrape COVID-19 data from the Greek Ministry of Health's daily reports, which are posted online in PDF format. I'm using wget to download them, then PyPDF2 to scrape them for data:

```
import wget
import PyPDF2

wget.download('https://eody.gov.gr/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/covid-gr-daily-report-23-09-2020.pdf')
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader('covid-gr-daily-report-23-09-2020.pdf')
```

But it returns the following error:

```
PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: Could not read malformed PDF file
```

The PDF that's saved in the directory will not open either.

How can I save the PDF so that it doesn't get malformed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content you are trying to download is protected by a Google reCAPTCHA.  If you look at the response text you should see that:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://eody.gov.gr/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/covid-gr-daily-report-23-09-2020.pdf')

print(r.text)
```

This is the response.  You'd need to overcome that I'm not a robot security first:

```
<html>
<head>
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
</script>
<body>
</body></html>
```